# If $\frac{dS_t}{S_t} = f(t)dW_t$, calculate $\int_0^TS_tdt$ or find its distribution

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Given the stochastic process $S_t$  $$\frac{dS_t}{S_t} = f_tdW_t$$

Calculate $\int_0^TS_tdt$ or find its distribution

**My attempt**: We have $S_t = S_0\exp(-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^tf_s^2ds+\int_0^tf_sdW_s)$. Hence,

\begin{align}
\int_0^TS_tdt &=TS_T - \int_0^TtdS_t \\
&=TS_T - \int_0^Ttf_tS_tdW_t \\
&=TS_0\exp(-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^Tf_t^2dt+\int_0^Tf_tdW_t) - S_0\int_0^T \left(tf_t\exp(-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^tf_s^2ds+\color{red}{\int_0^tf_sdW_s})\right)dW_t \\
\end{align}

I don't know whether it is possible to simplify the second term (the integral with the integrand containing a stochastic integral $\color{red}{\int_0^tf_sdW_s}$) such that there is no stochastic integral in integrand.

What is the distribution of the integral of a log-normal distribution?

Comment: where did you find this problem? There's an article of Yor dealing with the integral of a geometric brownian motion (just letting the $f_s$ be constant, but the results are extremely complicated

Comment: @Chaos I try to price a call option in a stochastic volatility model framework where the stochastic variance $\sigma_t^2$ is a log-normal process. Yes, now it seems to me that a closed-form expression of the integral of  $\sigma_t^2$ is quite complicated.

Comment: you can take a look to the article  I mentioned before https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-56634-9_3  but I suspect that a closed form for this integral would be quite complex

Comment: @Chaos Thank you very much!